# C++ class with all members and methods static

Tags: c++, static, static-classes

I got a program with multiple classes and have one class that has all members and methods static with the following content: two members and two methods to initializate them at start. Also all the members in my static class are public. My question is, if this is a bad practice or if there is any better way to do it? I use the members of this class only in one of the another classes.

Comment: If you initialize something at run time, what is the point to make all functions static? Why don't you make a class object static instead?

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class.

Comment: Your `class` is now essentially just a `namespace`.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345956/advantages-of-classes-with-only-static-methods-in-c

Comment: This is really useful and exactly what i was looking for, thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always **avoid creating useless symbols**.

If there is no need for a class, create a set of functions in a namespace. If your set of functions needs to manipulate some data, a static class/singleton is the way to go.

My rule when I design an application is to avoid having stuff that is callable from anywhere.

***The more you restrict yourself*** (Or the user in the case of a library), **the safer your code is** (Less bugs due to bad usage).

If you really need to make a static class, I can suggest you to use a constructor like this one:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() = delete;
};
```

It avoid confusion between an instanciable class and a completely static class.

If you like flourishes you can setup something like that:

```
#define STATIC_CLASS(class_name) public: class_name() = delete

class Foo
{
    STATIC_CLASS(Foo);
};
```