# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Simply asked: What is going wrong here?!

```
class c {
  public:
  static void v() {
    int var = 0;
  }

  static int i() {
    return 1;
  }
};

c::i(); // Throws error message
c::v(); // Also throws error message

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

The error message(s) are:

> Compiling sketch...
>
> /tmp/698769749/CompilingTests/CompilingTests.ino:12:7: error: expected
>   constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
>
> c::i();
>
> ^
>
> /tmp/698769749/CompilingTests/CompilingTests.ino:13:7: error: expected
>   constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
>
> c::v();
>
> ^
>
> exit status 1

What should this error message tell me?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `c::i();` and the next lines?

Comment: `c::i(); // Throws error message
c::v(); // Also throws error message
` what should this even mean?

Comment: FWIW, I find classes with nothing but static functions to be a bit of a smell. Some discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/134540/7740) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7345956/10077).

Comment: @YSC I wanted to know, what he is trying to achieve with this lines, not what the compiler output is. The same what Hawky asked

Comment: I removed the unnecessary code and broke it down to the most necessary content.

Answer (score 3):

Statements `c::i()` and `c::v()` are not allowed in the global scope, they should be enclosed inside a function. Also, those static member functions should be declared `public` in order to be accessible outside `c`:

```
struct c {

  static void v() {
    int var = 0;
  }

  static int i() {
    return 1;
  }
};

void g()
{
    c::i();
    c::v();
}

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/whiDHh

Comment: I just saw the `public`problem and fixed this in my post. I "forgot" to put the statements into `setup()` (it might be obvious that I'm quite new to C++...). I just didn't understand the error message. Thank you!

Comment: @alve89 understanding C++ diagnostics is a hard skill in itself.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems that stands out is that your functions don't have public access.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206467/discussion-on-answer-by-anastaciu-error-expected-constructor-destructor-or-ty).